# How to correctly map a OneToMany relationship in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Hello I am working on a Spring Boot project and I am a little bit confused. I have a `Product` entity and a `Property` entity and they look like this:

```
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Property> properties;
//getters and setters omitted
}
```

```
public class Property {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String value;
//getters and setters omitted
}
```

Now I am wondering if I will need to also specify a ManyToOne relationship in the Propery entity or is this good enough? In my past projects where I tried using a relationship in both entities(biredctional) and that ended up being a mess because I often got stuck in a "infinite loop" of data when trying to retrieve it from my frontend. I only need a unidirectional and simple relationship where a single Product can have many Properties, and then I can retrieve the data with the getProperties() method. Am I understand something wrong or is my code good enough for what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a unidirectional @OneToMany association, it means you can only access the relationship from the parent side where the foreign key resides. [More Details here](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/)

The bidirectional associations should always be updated on both sides, therefore the Parent side should contain the addChild and removeChild combo. These methods ensure we always synchronize both sides of the association, to avoid object or relational data corruption issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to retrieve Products from a Property you don't need to map ManyToOne link. 
It's, in my humble opinion, always a good idea to code just what you really need.

There isn't "good" implementation universally good, just a solution which fit more your need and it's easiest to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product" ,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Property> properties;
}


public class Property {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String value;

    @ManyToOne
    private Product prodcut;
}
```

You should annotate the Many part of the relationship as well `(@ManyToOne)`.
And you should also specify, in the Product entity, that the Property entity will do the mapping in the DB `( @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product" ,cascade = CascadeType.ALL))`.

Check above code for modifications.